Auto-generated Dependency Acknowledgements from SPM and Cocoapods in Settings.Bundle
I am working on multiple projects which rely on SPM and Cocoapods. Whenever possible I use SPM, but for some I am force to stick with Pods. At the moment i am looking into auto generating an Acknowledgement section to the Settings.Bundle. There are a few tools around, some older, some newer, but i have not been able to find one which can combine SPM and Cocoapods dependencies.
Is there a technical limitation i am unaware of?
Which tool are capable of doing what i look for?
Tools i have found but are not sufficient:
https://github.com/FelixHerrmann/swift-package-list (SPM only)
https://cocoapods.org/pods/Acknowlist (no settings bundle option)
https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-acknowledgements (Pod only)
edit
Thanks to the input from @cristallo this is the Build script i use now. It is a slightly tweaked version of what is described in the readme of LicensePlist to fix Apple Silicon issues and warn if the tool is not installed (which is quite practical if multiple people work on the project)
# Adds support for Apple Silicon brew directory
if [[ "$(uname -m)" == arm64 ]]; then
    export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
fi

if command -v license-plist &> /dev/null; then
    license-plist --output-path $PRODUCT_NAME/Settings.bundle
else
    echo "warning: license-plist not installed"
fi


I am using LicensePlist. It collects all packages licenses then show up in the Settings app.
https://github.com/mono0926/LicensePlist
It supports both SPM and CocoaPods

Thank for pointing me in this direction, i'll look into it
